# How to show custom customer attribute in customer grid dynamically using backend grid

Tags: magento-2.1, customer

In magento 2, I am working on extension manage customer attributes. I want to show custom customer attribute added to show on customer grid.

I set attribute values like is_used_in_grid=1, is_visible_in_grid=1 , is_filterable_in_grid=1 and is_searchable_in_grid=1 but still attribute is not displaying on customer grid.

I found one solution here [How do you add a custom attribute to the customer grid in adminhtml (Magento2)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121053/how-do-you-add-a-custom-attribute-to-the-customer-grid-in-adminhtml-magento2) 
This solution uses Ui component, I want to show custom customer attributes dynamicaly on customer grid. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to create ui_component file in custom extension.

KTPL/Customerattribute/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <listingToolbar name="listing_top"/>
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="nick_name" class="KTPL\Customerattribute\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Nickname">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Nick Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

second step : KTPL/Customerattribute/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Nickname.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace KTPL\Customerattribute\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Nickname extends Column
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param ContextInterface   $context           
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory   
     * @param array              $components        
     * @param array              $data              
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) 
            {

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($item['entity_id']);

                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $customer->getNickName();
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

After applying this you need flush cache and setup:upgrade.

Comment: @ Praksash Patel -  I am managing attributes from back end using extension manage customer attributes. I want dynamic solution. so that I do this from backend.